# Copy distinct values in excel from one range to another

Tags: spreadsheet, google-docs

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
A       B
food    12
cars    30
cars    40
food    10
food    14
living  100
fun     30
food    40
```

I'd like to copy all distinct values from column A to some other location (for example column D) - for this example it would contain values:

```
food
cars
living
fun
```

is there a way to do this in Google Docs spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=Unique(A1:A10) should do the trick :)